# What is the "fourth term" of the Hegelian dialectic?

Tags: reference-request, hegel, badiou

> Paul accomplishes his objective only by defining a fourth discourse, which could be called mystical, as the margin for his own. As if every schema of discourses had to configure a quadrangle. **But is it not Hegel who illuminates this point when, at the end of his *Logic,* he shows that absolute Knowledge of a ternary dialectic requires a fourth term?**

(Alain Badiou, *[Saint Paul: The Foundation of Universalism](https://archive.org/details/saintpaulfoundat0000badi)*, p. 49)

What exactly is this "fourth term" of the dialectic that Badiou is speaking of? I'd especially appreciate a reference to the exact place where this is discussed/introduced in the *Science of Logic.*

Comment: See [here](https://www.radicalphilosophyarchive.com/issue-files/rp58_article1_whyshouldadialecticianlearntocounttofour_zizek.pdf)